# jQuery TextExt set autocomplete suggestions to filter based on 'contains' rather than 'starts with'

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, autocomplete, jquery-textext

I have some data like this in my Json file:

```
"Microsoft word"
"adobe Photoshop"
"PHP programming"
```

When i enter `PHP` in my text input, [TextExt](http://textextjs.com/) suggest me `PHP Programming`.
But when i enter `Program` in text input, don't suggest any tag.

So `autocomplete` in TextExt just find first characters of any words.
How i can fix this ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like there's an open issue with a work around:
https://github.com/alexgorbatchev/jquery-textext/issues/168

You can override how the `ItemManager` filters its list of suggestions:

```
p.itemContains = function(item, needle)
{
    return this.itemToString(item).toLowerCase().indexOf(needle.toLowerCase()) > -1;
};
```

The issue suggests modifying their core js file but you could always provide your own `ItemManager` via the options or monkey patch `ItemManager`.